# I want to track the path of particle for ONE HOUR by solving the equation of motion. For time step, t= np. arange(0, 3600,10). Is this correct?

Tags: numpy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, odeint

I want to track the path of particles for one hour by solving the equation of motion.  I generate multiple points in time:
`t = np. arange(0,3600,10)`.

Does the time duration depends on the time step?
If we write the times as `t = np.arange(0,3600,0.2)`, will we still get a vector of time samples which reflects one hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `numpy.arange(start=0,stop=3600,step,...)` the duration of your measurement does not equal one hour. This fact is caused by the half-open interval [*start*, *stop*) which is used to generate your vector (Note: Your *stop* value is not included in the generated vector. Thus, the duration does not equal *stop* - *start*). If you really want your measurement duration to equal one hour you can use `numpy.linspace(...,endpoint=True)`.

```
import numpy as np

start = 40       # Start in seconds [s]
stop = 3600      # Stop in seconds [s]
N = 3            # Number of samples (N must not be 1)
t = np.linspace(start, stop, N, endpoint=True)

D = t[-1] - t[0]
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you please elaborate on the choice of 40s rather than 0s. If one is interested in evaluating from time Zero (initial time) will giving 40s as start means we have miss the time from 0s to 40 s?

Comment: Yes, the choice of 40s as a starting value was an arbitrary decision. Of course you have to use 0s so that our measurement duration is 3600s. I just wanted to show with my example how to use np.linspace.

Comment: Thank you for sharing me your knowledge and helping me clarifying my doubts.